# tensorflow build error with bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

i'm trying to build tensorflow from source on Ubuntu14.04 with python2.7, no GPU. when i execute `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` on console, it says:

```
ERROR:
/home/yangyang/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:23:1:
error loading package 'tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle': Encountered
error while reading extension file 'protobuf.bzl': no such package
'@protobuf//': Proxy address https://127.0.0.1:8123/ is not a valid
URL and referenced by
'//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build
aborted.
```

i'm not familiar with bazel and don't quite understand the error. it's true that i'm using polipo and global proxy on 127.0.0.1:8123. but i don't understand why and how this affects bazel. i also tried stop polipo and banned the global proxy. then git clone a fresh copy of tensorflow and do the build again. but the same error still exist. does anybody know the reason? thanks!

Comment: did you run `./configure` ?
can you run with `bazel build -s //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` and paste the output?

Answer (score 9):

Bazel didn't handle proxies with a trailing slash up until [18 days ago](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/1d9761390dddf4d577e06dad790d92f354187a9d), so it's not in a release yet.  Can you set your HTTPS_PROXY environment variable to be `https://127.0.0.1:8123`, instead?

You might have to do a `bazel clean --expunge` before rebuilding, I'm not sure if the proxy URL is cached.